# How to aggregate scan result of a multi-module maven project with complicated parent structure in jQAssistant?

Tags: maven, jqassistant

I am having a problem regarding aggregating the data of a multi-module maven project in a single store directory using `-Djqassistant.useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot=true`.

Here is how my project is structured

```
root-project [NO PARENT]
----/project-A [PARENT company-parent-pom-A]
----/project-B [PARENT company-parent-pom-B]
```

I am running the following on the root project

`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true com.buschmais.jqassistant:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan -Djqassistant.useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot=true`

But it shows following error.

`Failed to execute goal com.buschmais.jqassistant:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan (default-cli) on project root-project: Cannot re-use store instance from reactor. Either declare the plugin as extension or execute Maven using the property -Djqassistant.store.lifecycle=MODULE on the command line.`

So I add `-Djqassistant.store.lifecycle=MODULE` and run the following

`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true com.buschmais.jqassistant:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan -Djqassistant.useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot=true -Djqassistant.store.lifecycle=MODULE`

Now the build succeeds. But while scanning the root-project in the end the plugin resets the store directory. So all the data collected before gets removed. Is this an issue of jqa-maven-plugin or am I doing something wrong?

```
19984 [INFO] --- jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan (default-cli) @ project-B ---
22034 [INFO] Loaded jQAssistant plugins [Common, Core Analysis, JUnit, Java, Maven 3, XML].
22082 [INFO] Opening store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.
24227 [INFO] Resetting store.
27464 [INFO] Reset finished.
28887 [INFO] Entering /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-B/target/classes
29861 [INFO] Leaving /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-B/target/classes (183 entries, 972 ms)
29864 [INFO] Entering /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-B/target/test-classes
29874 [INFO] Leaving /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-B/target/test-classes (12 entries, 10 ms)
30823 [INFO] Closing store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.

...

124415 [INFO] --- jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan (default-cli) @ project-A ---
124423 [INFO] Opening store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.
124971 [INFO] Entering /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-A/target/classes
124973 [INFO] Leaving /home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/project-A/target/classes (2 entries, 1 ms)
125222 [INFO] Closing store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.

...

138156 [INFO] --- jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.2.0:scan (default-cli) @ root-project ---
139411 [INFO] Loaded jQAssistant plugins [Common, Core Analysis, JUnit, Java, Maven 3, XML].
139448 [INFO] Opening store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.
140780 [INFO] Resetting store.
146562 [INFO] Reset finished.
147842 [INFO] Closing store in directory '/home/mehedi/Develop/WorkSpace/jqa-projects/test-project/target/jqassistant/store'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup you're describing should be working so likely you found a bug. Can you report this please on https://github.com/buschmais/jqa-maven-plugin?